# Apache2.2 - Unable to connect?

Tags: linux, debian, web-hosting, apache-2.2

I followed the tutorial at http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/412 and I did everything it said but my site isn't showing it just says "Unable to Connect" when I try and visit the address in my browser.

I am using Apache2.2 on Debian Lenny.  I have multiple IPs/RDNS configurations on this server, and I know for a fact that they all work.  How do I fix it?  My httpd.conf is empty, my apache2.conf and ports.conf are the defaults.  Here is what my sites-enabled configuration for my site looks like:

```
    <VirtualHost *80>
    ServerAdmin mysite@mydomain.com
    ServerName  www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com

    # Indexes + Directory Root.
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /home/user1/www/www.mydomain.com/htdocs/

    # CGI Directory
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/user1/www/www.mydomain.com/cgi-bin/
    <Location /cgi-bin>
            Options +ExecCGI
    </Location>


    # Logfiles
    ErrorLog  /home/user1/www/www.mydomain.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /home/user1/www/www.mydomain.com/access.log combined
```

`

Answer (score 3):

You should have a colon between the asterisk and the port number in the VirtualHost directive.

Such as: `<VirtualHost *:80>`
You should also have a closing "tag": `</VirtualHost>`.

Also check the log files to see what more is wrong.

`netstat -nap|egrep -e 'apache|httpd'` should show you what port and IP address apache is listening on, if it is up.